# Scrapy not crawling pages

Tags: python, scrapy

I have no idea what's wrong with this spider, but it won't crawl any pages:

```
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

from paper_crawler.items import PaperCrawlerItem

class PlosGeneticsSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'plosgenetics'
    allowed_domains = ['plosgenetics.org']
    start_urls = ['http://www.plosgenetics.org/article/browse/volume']

    rules = [
        Rule( SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(),restrict_xpaths=('//ul[@id="journal_slides"]')), callback='parse_item', follow=True)
        ]


    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.log(response.url)
        print response.url

        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select('//div[@class="item cf"]')
        items = []
        for title in titles:
            item = PaperCrawlerItem()
            item['title'] = "".join(title.xpath('.//div[@class="header"]//h3//a[contains(@href,"article")]/text()').extract()).strip()
            item['URL'] = title.xpath('.//div[@class="header"]//h3//a[contains(@href,"article")]/@href').extract()
            item['authors'] = "".join(title.xpath('.//div[@class="header"]//div[@class="authors"]/text()').extract()).replace('\n', "")
            items.append(item)

        return(items)
```

The syntax looks right but it keeps saying `INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)`

Any ideas on how I messed up?

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious mistake I can spot is your in CrawlSpider.rules definition, which should be a tuple, you'll find the fix in the first answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223531/scrapy-crawler-in-python-cannot-follow-links).

But in short, CrawlSpider.rules should be:

```
rules = (Rule(...),Rule(...),)
```

Notice the bracket and comma.

Comment: That doesn't look like the problem (I'm also not working on this anymore). `rules` only needs to be iterable. If it's a tuple with one element and no comma, it won't be iterable (just like in that question), but if it's a list, it will be iterable. This is easy to check with `object.__iter__`: `["test"].__iter__` will return a method wrapper, but `("test").__iter__` will not